# inverse of iloc method in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Good morning
I would like to know how to obtain the inverse of iloc. starting from a date index, starting from the date I want to get the number 0,1,2, ...
For example, starting from this dataset:

```
days = pd.date_range('2007-07-01', '2007-07-05', freq='1D')
np.random.seed(seed=1111)
value1 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'dt': days, 'value1':value1}).set_index('dt')
print(df)
```

I can get the individual values via the iloc method:

```
df.iloc[0]
df.iloc[1]
df.iloc[2]
df.iloc[3]
```

I would like to do the reverse process: starting from index dates (2007-07-01, 2007-07-02, 2007-07-03, ... ), get the corresponding locationn index - 0,1,2,3, ...

Answer (score 2):

If you type

```
df.index[0]
df.index[1]
df.index[2]
...
```

you'll get index value at certain numeric index.

If you want numeric index of a date, you can use
`df.index.get_loc('2007-07-04')`

Comment: Maybe I did not say it clear enough.
I give the index dates as input, and I want to get the row number as output:
Example
input: 2007-07-03
output: 2
In fact, doing df.iloc [2] I get 2007-07-03. Here I want to do it the other way around

Comment: You can use `df.index.get_loc(<date>)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.index`:

```py
df.index[0]
df.index[1]
```

or, even better, as a slice:

```py
df.index[0:3]
```

or

```py
df.index[[0,1,2,3,7,13]]
```

Comment: I want to get the position from the date. Example input: 2007-07-03 output: 2 In fact, doing df.iloc [2] I get 2007-07-03. Here I want to do it the other way around

Answer (score 0):

To index with your index values which is date in your case

```
df.loc['2007-07-01']
```

To index with location

```
df.index[0]
```

Comment: I want to get the position from the date